# CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl inside SingleChildScrollView not scrolling

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-cupertino

I am building in Flutter a custom Segmented Control that has too many options, so it should be scrolled horizontally to see all the options. That is the reason why I put the CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl inside a SingleChildScrollView with horizontal scrollDirection.

In the Android emulator works ok and scrolls, but on the ios emulator it doesn't scroll.

I don't know what am I doing wrong.

I share the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class CustomSegmentedControl extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomSegmentedControl({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomSegmentedControl> createState() => _CustomSegmentedControlState();
}

class _CustomSegmentedControlState extends State<CustomSegmentedControl> {
  // Por defecto le damos el valor de "todos".
  int? groupValue = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        children: const {
          0: Text("Todos"),
          1: Text("2005"),
          2: Text("2006"),
          3: Text("2007"),
          4: Text("2008"),
          5: Text("2009"),
          6: Text("2010"),
          7: Text("2011"),
          8: Text("2012"),
          9: Text("2013"),
        },
        groupValue: groupValue,
        onValueChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            groupValue = value;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the code you provided is working fine.

Comment: @eamirho3ein : Is working fine on Android but on iOS it doesn't scroll.

Answer (score 0):

It worked on android, but iOS not. The reason is flutter add drag event handler on this widget, so scroll event will not effect.

**Solution:** copy`CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl`'s file and remove the drag event code (like below image)

[image]